# Problem with Iterate/Aggregate in micro integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I don't know why, but aggregator does not work. Can someone please help?
There are no error or warn in logs

```xml
<iterate description="Start Iteration" expression="//ns1:user"
        id="UserIterate" xmlns:ns1="...">
        <target sequence="SyncItemSequence" />
        <property name="RESPONSE " scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    </iterate>
    <aggregate id="UserIterate">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" enclosingElementProperty="Info" expression="/s11:Envelope/s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | /s12:Envelope/s12:Body/child::*[position()=1]" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="Aggregate" value="ok"/>
            </log>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
```

This is SyncItemSequence.

```xml
<file.read configKey="FOTO_FILES_CONNECTION">
    ...
</file.read>
<header name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value=""/>
<payloadFactory description="Set ARGS for CALL" media-type="xml">
    ...
</payloadFactory>
<call blocking="true">
    ...
</call>
<header name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="urn:_poststatus"/>
<payloadFactory description="Set ARGS for UPDATE" media-type="xml">
    ...
</payloadFactory>
<call blocking="true">
    ...
</call>
```

Edit: Repet for questions

Comment: Show us what you have in `SyncItemSequence` and the response you get. Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: @ycr sorry for cenzure but stack have limit for lenght code. (Besides aggregate its work)